# Use another layout option instead of table

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to style my data using following layout:

```
------------------
|        |        |
|  CELL2 | CELL 1 |
|        |        |
|--------|        |
|        |        |
|  CELL3 |--------|
|        | CELL 4 |
------------------
```

OR  (if CELL2 is not present in html)

```
------------------
|        |        |
|  CELL3 | CELL 1 |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |--------|
|        | CELL 4 |
------------------
```

I dont want to use `table` for that purpose. What is the best option ?

The Cells are not always there. So CELL2 could be not present in html, but should be on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution for the 1234 block.
Two columns floating left. Each containing two rows.
Using padding style to position the text.

```
<style>
div{
border: 1px dotted #000;
}
</style>

<div style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left; padding:20px 10px;">CELL 2</div>
    <div style="float:left; clear:left; padding:20px 10px;">CELL 3</div>
</div>

<div style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left; padding:20px 10px 40px 10px;">CELL 1</div>
    <div style="float:left; clear:left; padding:10px;">CELL 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Naturally this is simply to give you the gist of it.